# Too many photos

Tags: icloud, photos

I have a fairly common issue.
I love how the photos are managed in Photos, but I have too many of them, collected during the years (and the situation will only get worse).
I have a 256GB Macbook air M1, and probably more than 256GB of pictures.

I thought I can have as many photos in iCloud as the storage allows, but I think I'm constrained by the size of the laptop.
I'm very puzzled since it means that I can have as many photos as the smallest of my devices.
Am I correct? is there an alternative option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to Photos app > Preferences > enable Optimize Mac Storage. That will add caching features that seamlessly remove older photos locally when running out of space. You won't notice a difference, basically.

Comment: But how can I have > 256GB of picture on iCloud (I have 2TB of space) starting from a laptop with a 256GB HD?

Comment: Because your laptop isn't storing full copies of the photos unless you look at them, which caches the full photo temporarily. I'm sure there's other requirements too like recent photos are probably all present on the device.